# Can I run aws cdk deploy as an aws lambda service?

Tags: aws-cdk

Can I `cdk deploy` from an aws lambda (preferably python)?

Example workflow:

- Lambda is triggered by e.g. S3 File upload
- Lambda runs `cdk deploy`

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend to create a CodeBuild that runs the command and invoke that from the Lambda instead.

Lambda has a 15 minute timeout limit whereas CodeBuild is much more relaxed in that regard and, being a full blown virtual machine, you get all the benefits of being able to utilise other OS level dependencies like Docker for asset bundling.

Trying to do it inside a Lambda you will either hit timeouts or inability to use os dependencies or disk space issues somewhere down the road inevitably.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing officially supported but worth checking out this:

https://github.com/misterjoshua/cdk-lambda-deploy

Answer (score 1):

It's possible. I use [lambda container image](https://dev.to/vumdao/quick-start-lambda-container-image-using-aws-cdk-2-0-1ifc) to daily deploy/destroy test environments.